# Como obter id de um Drawable pelo nome

Tags: android

Tentei assim mais está retornando 0

```
try {
        String nome_foto = itens.get(position).nome_foto;
        int drawableId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(nome_foto, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        Log.e("",""+drawableId+" "+R.drawable.bertioga1+" "+nome_foto);
        imagem.setImageResource(drawableId );
    }
```

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de `nome_foto`?

Comment: o nome da foto que esta no drawable , tipo foto1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você já estiver no contexto principal não precisa de "context". Veja também 
se está pegando o nome da foto corretamente. Testei assim e funcionou perfeitamente:

```
String nomeFoto = "nome_da_foto"; //sem o PGN, JPG, etc...
int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(nomeFoto, "drawable", getPackageName());

imagem.setImageResource(drawableId );
```